# MSChart doesn't work when project gets downgraded

Tags: c#, .net, mschart, downgrade

I have a problem, that I created a project under 4.5 Framework, then downgraded it to 3.5, but MSChart doesn't work, even if it's supposed to work under 3.5. I have removed and readded references, doesn't help at all.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes, I got a bunch of them, all of them are refering to code parts, which include any references to the chart, like series, chart area and chart itself.

Comment: Oh, and I got 2 warnings refering to dll's: Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Design.dll' is incorrectly specified as a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful here, because .net 4 was a benchmark.

If you have a .net 4 executable, then it can reference a .net 2 library no problem. (Bear in mind here that .net 2, 3 and 3.5 were all essentially .net 2)

However if you have a .net 2 executable and try to reference a .net 4 library, its not going to work.

I suspect you have the latter. Running under .net 3.5 effectively gives you a .net 2 executable. If the MsChart component is built as a .net 4 component, then you'll have problems.

I'd double-check the version of MsChart you're referencing here. Just removing and readding might not be enough if you're re-adding the wrong version.

Comment: Official downloadable MSChart content is for 3.5 SP1. I Tried to create a fresh project under 3.5, but it still doesn't work.Maybe is is because I work in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: you can prove or disprove this if you have VS2008 on your machine

Comment: So VS2012 then? Not something I've used in anger yet - I'm just picking it up now. I'd Be interested to know how you solved it (assuming you did!)

Comment: I grew tired of trying to get it to work under VS2012, so I just continued the project on VS 2010.

Comment: yeah that's really crappy behaviour from VS2012.